# How can I avoid image reflow in Angular when I don't know the aspect ratio of the image?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to use the [padding bottom hack](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/say-no-to-image-reflow/) (illustrated below) to stop reflow upon image load for an Angular website. The problem is that I don't know the aspect ratio of the image, as it is user specified. Is it possible to stop image reflow when the dimensions of the image are unknown? I've found examples of getting the image dimensions using javascript, but that seems to happen after the page is already loaded. Can I get the height an width of the image in the component before load? I have access to the image source in the component.

```
index.html
----------
<div class="img-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: calc((400/600)*100%);">
  <img src="example.jpg" />
</div>

styles.css
----------
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Why not put a fixed dimensions first then change it according to the given dimensions when user inputs it.

Comment: @Jhdcruz Sorry, I wrote that poorly. The user uploads the image to the server on a different page, so it is not being input, then updated on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Javascript `Image` object in code (memory) and read the aspect ratio that way.

```
let image = new Image();
let width: number;
let height: number;

image.onload = () => {
  { height, width } = image;
  const ratio = width / height;
}

newImg.src = 'Your source here'; // this must be done AFTER setting onload and will load the image.
```

Remember, setting the `src` of the image will load it, which is asynchronous. `onload` is the callback for when the image is loaded.

You could also just load it into the page via an `img` tag, initially style it so it's invisible and won't mess with the page layout (`position: absolute; opacity: 0` or something similar), then grab the element with the `Renderer2` and read its `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` as it exists in the page, then alter styling accordingly and show the image.

EDIT: Here's my own [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htkkxp) of the above done in an Angular-ly fashion. It  transforms `onload` into an `Observable`, prefetches the image, does some calculations, and then uses the `Renderer2` to append it to the DOM. I'm calculating how to preserve the aspect ratio if you want one dimension to be 200px maximum, but that's just an example.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly (I definitely could be way off), then don't I have to wait for the image to be loaded before I get the height and width? In that case, the reflow will still occur. I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xa7g1) to show me trying to implement your answer.

Comment: @Courtney What I meant is that you *do* need to wait for it to load in order to get the height and width. That's why setting the `onload` callback is important, and must be done before you try and load the image. I've forked your stackblitz and 'Angularized' it with Observables and the like. went a little crazy with calculations, actually. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htkkxp

Comment: Thank you for all your work on this! In your forked example, the reflow problem still occurs. Do you have any suggestions for fixing that?

Comment: I just thought of waiting for the image to load as a conditional for the template. I added it to my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xa7g1) and it seems to work.